# What would the effects be of a warm, sunny tropical island located in polar waters?

Tags: biology, magic, climate, weather

So, suppose there exists an island (roughly the same size as Hawaii's big island) which is located well in the Arctic (or Antarctic) Circle, but magically has a tropical rainforest climate (warm temperatures, lots of rain, and bright sunlight even when the rest of the hemisphere is experiencing polar night.)

The climate is maintained by magical means, and has existed this way since before the evolution of modern humans, at the very least. It may have existed this way for much longer. At least part of the magic works by maintaining an artificial sun over the island (much smaller than the real one, located within the upper atmosphere. The artificial sun does not provide significant light or heat outside of the island's immediate vicinity.)

This artificial sun shines only on the island and the water within an arbitrary distance. Let's say that this distance is five miles, just for the sake of argument.

What climatic effects would this have on the island (outside of the artificial tropical climate), the local region, and the world as a whole? I am looking for weather, climate, and biological effects particularly, but any other notable effects I would like to hear.

Comment: It's magic -- science doesn't really apply, so the effect is whatever you think it is.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon I am interested in the way that this magic might interact with real world climate and weather physics, and how life might respond to those conditions.

Comment: Voted -1, because there is no Magic tag. Any answer will have to take into account, the heat on the island is unspecified and of unknown origin. For example, an island in the polar region could be warm, because of magic "vulcanic" activity. But in that case, the heat would come from below, which does not help plant life and yield an island not looking tropical. When there would be an artificial sunlight of some kind, you'd have to explain why that sun only affects the island and not its surroundings. A very artificial (magic, constructed) scenario, in need of a Magic tag !

Comment: Is there a forcefield of some kind that is impervious to winds and oceanic currents? Also, how far beyond the coastline does the sunlet's output affect? And finally, how much heat & light are thinking is "not significant"? How much water could it reasonably heat if the island is in the middle of say the Antarctic current?

Comment: @Goodies I have added the magic tag

Comment: @elemtilas There is no force field. Rather, this artificial sun shines only on the island and the water within an arbitrary distance. Let's say that distance is five miles.

Comment: I'll swap my vote, ok

Comment: rain. lots and lots and lots of rain. Permanent massive convection cell over the island, dumping tons of water. Also some winds as the air rushes in, and some flooding as the rain washes out.

Comment: What happens to the water surrounding the island? Is it magically warm for the 5 miles? Does it magically warm any sea water which moves into the area? What about water which moves out of the area? Does exiting water retain the heat or is it magically removed again? Most likely there's a current which flows past the island and large amounts of water moving in and out of the area. In other words, is the heat energy magically retained in the affected area, or is it dissipated into the surrounding environment?

Comment: @Makyen Suppose for the time being that the only magical effect is the artificial sun. If there is a strong current, any heat in that water leaves the island.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Result

*Permanent* hurricane, one order of magnitude more powerful than your run of the mill ones.

And you can forget "the eye of the hurricane" - that happens when the hurricane gathers energy over large expanses of warm ocean water.
For this one, it is the center of the thing where the energy is pumped into the air column - you will get a permanent warm (say at 293K) whirlwind, ascending in the center, fed at the base by a cold air (at 253K) rushing in from all sides and subject to Coriolis "force"
<sup>(if you remember, the strength of the Coriolis effect is the strongest at the poles, it goes with the $sin(latitude)$).</sup>
[A fire-tornado of sorts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BxQd6AGYiI), not that hot as one over a forest fire, but quite strong with the amount of incoming power (over a small surface) it has to dissipate.

#### Production

Hawaii has a surface area of 28,311 km² = 28.311e9m². Is situated on 19.8968° N latitude - in average per year it receives ([Lambert's cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law)) 94% of the total energy flux of a surface with the solar radiation at normal incidence.

The solar constant at Earth surface after passing through atmosphere on a sunny day is [1025W/m²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant#Variations_due_to_atmospheric_conditions).

The total power your island receives is $28.311e9 m^2 \cdot 1025W/m^2 \cdot 0.94 = 2.73e13W = 27.2TW$

First perspective point - the total power the island receives is:

- about a Hiroshima bomb exploring every 2.4 seconds (and having the energy dissipated over the entire area of the island)
- about 12 times the average electric power generated on Earth in 2008 (which is [2311.4GW = 2.3114TW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_generation#Production))

#### Consumption

Let's say that the island is all green and lush at a moment (won't be for long, I promise). Some energy will go into photosynthesis - say about 5% of it (yes, plants have [terrible efficiencies in using the energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency#Plants) - lucky us, we can keep warmer)

Part of the energy will go in making the rain. Oh, hang on, the same energy that goes into evaporating water is released when the water condenses and falls as rain. So no, while there may be some fluctuations, on average there's no actual consumption, just forget I considered it.

Part of the energy will escape to the vacuum of space as radiation. That's again a bit [6/117 = 5.1%](http://www.ces.fau.edu/nasa/module-2/energy-budget.php) (look at "The Radiation Balance at Earth’s Surface" and note the "Only 6 of these 117 units are emitted into space beyond Earth’s atmosphere").
<sup>actually, that's a nice diagram</sup>

Let's say part of it is used by the inhabitants - hang on, unless they use the energy to create fuel (eerrr.... energy rich substances, that they'll export as such, as an energy sink), that part of the energy they are "using" is actually transformed back into heat. No dice.

So, bottom line. 10% of the energy lost on any other ways except heating the air. Which means the 90% (= 24.48TW) rest of the 27.7TW is going to heat the air above the island. That's gonna be quite an impressive [thermal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal), the paragliders there should be delighted, isn't it? Well, isn't it?

Except... *that* the temperature differential between the island and the rest of the frozen sea around and that lotsa cold air that will want to get warm itself above your beautiful island! **And that spells a huge trouble**

**Second perspective point**

**The power developed by a hurricane winds  [is a puny 1.5 terrawatts](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/can-we-capture-energy-hurricane-180960750/). And you have 16 times more to dissipate in an area thousands time smaller than the one a hurricane spans!**

> So while wind is only a small part of the overall energy output of a hurricane, it still generates vast amounts of power: around 1.5 terawatts, or just over a quarter of the world’s current total electrical generating capacity of 5.25 terawatts.

What happens when an underwater volcano dumps [1-2TW](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-22439-y) in the ocean - megaplumes dispersing ashes over 10–150km3 areas.

---

Bottom line, just forget about the magic, the nature is way more than your magic can imagine.

Comment: What about the eye of the hurricane? If this hurricane is permanent and sitting in place, would the eye not be relatively calm?

Comment: @Globin347 That eye of normal hurricane comes from the heat energy pumped in the storm from the large surface of heated water in the ocean - energy is mostly on the periphery of the hurricane's eye. What you have here is more of a draft chimney with the fire in the center; that center is where the things will go crazy, pushing warm air towards the top and sucking clod air from below. In that center, you'll have a [tornado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoQr-pDaQNw).

Comment: Would all those storm clouds block the sunlight from reaching the ground?

Comment: @Globin347 occasionally it might happen, but the energy keeps coming (if not, the surface will freeze rapidly), the water vapors are pretty good in absorbing heat so they'll dissipate pretty quick. I don't know the weather where you live, but think fog in the morning that "raises" as soon as the temperature jumps one or two degrees. Besides, how much water is on your island?

Comment: *"Only 6 of these 117 units are emitted into space beyond Earth’s atmosphere":* There must be some small print somewhere because I am absolutely certain that just about *all* the energy **must** eventually be re-radiated into space beyond Earth's atmosphere; otherwise after a very short geological time the accumulated energy will bring the surface of the Earth in thermal equilibrium with the surface of the Sun. (Only "about" all because some tiny amount of energy may be stored in long-term reservoirs such as coal seams or petroleum deposits.)

Comment: @AlexP - dispersed on height with the rising air and _dissipated at night time_ This second thing is something that the "Santa Claus tropical paradise" can't afford due to the abrupt gradient with the surrounding temperatures. Low albedo of a land surface transforms it into a very close to 100% efficient light-to-heat transformer - 71% of water surface is nice for the entire Earth, but wasn't specified in the OP. Water evaporation is quite a good cooling factor but the island is land, how much water can you put on top until is no longer an island?

Comment: At the summer solstice on the south pole, we have solar radiation of 450 W/m^2 as measured by the LI-200SZ radiometer. That is about half what you calculate. Why don't we see smaller tornadoes than the one you describe above the south pole because of this?

Comment: All these comparisons to Hiroshima etc. seem a bit silly to me, given that any normal tropical island receives and dissipates the exact same amount of energy and we don't see constant super-hurricanes over those. You're right that there's lots of cold air around, but the humidity is generally very low in the arctic circle, so I'm skeptical it would lead to a hurricane as such, though I agree the weather would be constantly windy and very weird.

Comment: @D.J.Klomp perhaps because at the South Pole you don't have a direct insolation with Hawaii levels _from an effing big artificial sun hanging just above a small island_ as requested by the OP? Maybe also because the South Pole has an albedo that a land island can't match?

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment: the main energy source for a hurricane is not insolation directly but the release of latent heat from condensation. This releases energy that was gathered over a very large area when that water evaporated. The situation here would be quite different, because the magic sun is only shining on a few square miles of water, so you wouldn't have that energy source and it might not be as energetic as you think. (But then again it might be, one would have to do some calculations to know for sure.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Hiroshima aside, on a honest-to-God plain tropical island you have heaps of water around to carry of the heat and you have nighttime during which those 6% IR to space continues without the continuous addition of energy just to fend freezing air just two steps away from the tropical temperature that you want to maintain.

Comment: I guess one thing we can say is that the weather is not going to be warm, unless the artificial sun is much stronger than the real one. As soon as the air is a few degrees higher than the surrounding air it will start to rise and draw in more Arctic winter air from the surroundings. So the air on the island will be constantly a few degrees higher than the air around it, but quite likely still below zero for much of the year.

Comment: @Nathaniel re addendum - that heat was still caused by insolation heating massive amounts of water until it can hold back no more. And proper tornadoes happen on [dry land too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_Alley) too.

Comment: Yeah, but we're only talking a few square miles here - the air won't pick up much moisture at all before it rises and gets replaced with new dry, cold air.

Comment: @Nathaniel yes, and that 1kW/sqm insolation needs to get somewhere, air being quite transparent. With the lack of water, it can only heat the soil which heats the air. Without any sink (except the 6% IR going into space), you'll effectively have winds dissipating 20TW+ of power all the time. I simply can't guess the dynamic equilibrium point for the temperature, it may be 500km/h frozen winds or maybe a balmy 10C 300km/h ones.

Comment: The same 1kW/m^2 insolation has to get somewhere on any normal sunny winter's day elsewhere on Earth - it doesn't take necessarily take extreme weather to do it. (Which is not to say it can't drive extreme weather or that it wouldn't in this situation, just that it's not obvious.) The energy that needs to be dissipated is in the form of heat at whatever temperature the ground is at, and it's that temperature that determines the strength of the system. My guess is that the constant influx of freezing air will keep it relatively low, but I agree that the dynamic equilibrium is hard to predict.

Comment: "The same 1kW/m^2 insolation has to get somewhere on any normal sunny winter's day elsewhere on Earth - it doesn't take necessarily take extreme weather to do it."  The back of napkin calculation that I've done were possible because the system was so highly constrained it simply could not evolve in any other way. If some constraints are relaxed, the system becomes too chaotic [to get a proper answer on WB](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/215274/26061)

Comment: "The eye of the hurricane" requires clarification I think. It's a mathematical fact that any swirling mass of air will always have at least one stationary point inside it. You could (and would) have upward or downward wind, but there will still be a sweet spot where the wind is at least horizontally stationary, right?

Comment: @user22917 pragmatically, it doesn't help much if the sweet spot is 30m in diameter and it wanders chaotically over the map.

Answer (score 7):

**I assume you're asking, "what happens when the magic runs out?"**

Your island is maintained by magical means. Therefore, the only weather patterns inside the limit of the magic is what is defined by the magic. Paradise. Wonderful!

Outside that magical limit we have standard polar behavior. Bears. Days that are six months long (give or take). Cold. Bears. Occasional seals and some left over equipment from various expeditions to the pole that got lost. I mentioned bears....

The only question that makes sense here is, what happens at the *interface* between those two worlds? For some insight, let's turn to the [good folks at Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/video/143206/Weather-interaction-movement-temperatures-air-masses)

> Air masses are gigantic atmospheric volumes with very specific temperature and humidity characteristics. When two different air masses come into contact, they don't mix. They push against each other along a line called a front. When a warm air mass meets a cold air mass, the warm air rises since it is lighter. At high altitude it cools, and the water vapor it contains condenses. This type of front is called a warm front. It generates nimbostratus clouds, which can result in moderate rain. On the other hand, when a cold air mass catches up with a warm air mass, the cold air slides under the warm air and pushes it upward. As it rises, the warm air cools rapidly. This configuration, called a cold front, gives rise to cumulonimbus clouds, often associated with heavy precipitation and storms.
>
> As air masses move, pushed by winds, they directly influence the weather in the regions over which they pass. In this way, they help to circulate heat and humidity in the atmosphere.

This is your classic problem of an immovable object (your magic) meeting an unstoppable force (the polar climate). What do you get? ***Storms.*** What are you probably going to get?

*A permanent [Arctic Cyclone](https://hypotheticalhurricanes.fandom.com/wiki/Arctic_Cyclone).*

So, the denizens of your island would have a lovely view straight up. But in all other directions, it would be a bit like being on the [Truman Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truman_Show) from the inside.

Comment: "the denizens of your island would have a lovely view straight up. " that is, if they love the view of [a tornado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BxQd6AGYiI) as seen from the below.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Presumably the same magic that maintains the climate also prevents it from being destroyed by a giant permanent tornado.

Comment: @nick012000 I'm not quite convinced that the climate is actually maintained, the OP only specifies the presence of a "sun". If you note, in my answer I've done only computation based on the provided power, but I did nothing to compute the actual temperature near the land.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Not my problem (not yours, either). If the OP wants to clarify or correct my assumption, he/she is free to do so. Had I thought that detail mattered (it doesn't, IMO), I would have asked for a clarification on the question post.

Comment: This argument is my fault. I find it very difficult to specify all the various parts of a question. The fact that I said "at least part of the magic works via an artificial sun" doesn't help. In any case, for this question, I wanted to run on "hard magic" in which there are a minimal number of magical effects, which are reasonably well understood.

Comment: @Globin347 Don't worry about it. I think this is more Adrian trying to subvert competition for his answers (he's done this on a couple of Qs where he and I both answered) than any weakness real or imagined with your post.